# In Let'sEncrypt, I want to delete the certificate to noninteractive

Tags: ssl

I'm a Japanese who is not good at English and is asking questions with the help of Google translation. Please lend me your strength.

In Let'sEncrypt, I want to delete a certificate from noninteractive to script.
I'm trying to execute from a script like this,

> sudo certbot - auto delete - d foo.com - n

The following error log appears and deletion is not executed.

Missing command line flag or config entry for this setting:
Which certificate would you like to delete?
Choices: ['abcdef.com', 'foo.com']

I'd like to delete certificate files completely noninteractively, but please help me how to do it.

Comment: You can ask questions in Japanese here: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Thank you, I solved it.
Resolved by changing the option from - d to - cert - name.